# Use tap to test the output of a console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, tap

I've got a really basic script I'd like to be able to add coverage to using node-tap:

```
const chalk = require('chalk')

module.exports = skip = type => console.log(chalk.blue(`Skipping generation of ${type} due to user selection`))
```

All it does is display a console.log message to the user (it's a command-line app).

I've written the following tap test for it:

```
// test/hello-world.js
const t = require('tap')

const skip = require('../scripts/skip')

t.test('skip() Returns the expected console message', async t => {
    t.equal(skip('test'), "Skipping generation of test due to user selection`")
    t.end()
})
```

But obviously that fails as I'm not returning that message, I'm returning a console.log. So how do I test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this https://node-tap.org/docs/api/snapshot-testing/

it should be able to solve your problem

Comment: That did the job, thank you. I have a related problem but I'll ask that in another question.

Comment: @AlexFoxleigh How did this solve your problem? The node-tap documentation does not indicate that it snapshots STDOUT. You still have to pass a string value to `matchSnapshot`.